# integrate VSTS and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

I was looking on how to integrate VSTS and SharePoint online, so that i can automate the deployment of applications to SharePoint sites(Console Applications & Provided Hosted Apps(web application hosted on Azure).

I not able to see any valuable articles for reference.
Can somebody suggest on the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article, https://delucagiuliano.com/continuous-integration-and-deployment-for-your-sharepoint-framework-solutions/#.W6VGufZFxVR, and it's predecessors usefull. There are some errors to work through.